# Star rating widget not updating on iPad and iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone, ipad

I have implmented a custom star-rating widget in CSS an jQuery based on radio inputs. All works fine on desktop browsers and Android devices but it's not working on iPad an iPhone.

You can see my widget in action [here](http://www.peoplejob.com/register/).

On iPad (or iPhone) when I touch a star, it doesnt' remain checked.

Here is th full code: [A jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2g253m2/11/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="signup_form" class="custom" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="signup_form" action="">
  <div id="field_2">
    <input id="option_221" type="radio" title="Very Happy" value="Actual_job_rate_5" name="field_2" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom radio" ></span>
    <input id="option_220" type="radio" title="Happy" value="Actual_job_rate_4" name="field_2" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom radio" ></span>
    <input id="option_219" type="radio" title="Neutral" value="Actual_job_rate_3" name="field_2" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom radio" ></span>
    <input id="option_218" type="radio" title="Unhappy" value="Actual_job_rate_2" name="field_2" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom radio" ></span>
    <input id="option_217" type="radio" title="Very Unhappy" value="Actual_job_rate_1" name="field_2" style="display: none;">
    <span class="custom radio" ></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Star rating radio buttons */

form.custom #field_2:not(old) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9.5em;
  height: 1.9em;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: left;
}

form.custom #field_2:not(old) > input {
  margin-right: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

form.custom #field_2:not(old) > span.custom.radio {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://www.peoplejob.com/wp-content/themes/sweetdate-child/assets/images/star-off.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  border: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1.9em;
  height: 1.9em;
}

form.custom #field_2:not(old) > span.custom.radio:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1.9em;
  height: 1.9em;
  background: url('http://www.peoplejob.com/wp-content/themes/sweetdate-child/assets/images/star-on.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1.9em;
  height: 1.9em;
}

form.custom #field_2:not(old) > span.custom.radio:hover:before,
form.custom #field_2:not(old) > span.custom.radio:hover ~ span.custom.radio:before,
form.custom #field_2:not(:hover) >:checked ~ span.custom.radio:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
   var toggleRadio = function($element) {
    var $input = $element.prev(),
        $form = $input.closest('form.custom'),
        input = $input[0];

    if (false === $input.is(':disabled')) {
      $form.find('input:radio[name="' + $input.attr('name') + '"]').next().not($element).removeClass('checked');
      if ( !$element.hasClass('checked') ) {
        $element.toggleClass('checked');
      }
      input.checked = $element.hasClass('checked');

      $input.trigger('change');
    }
  };

 $(document).on('click', 'form.custom span.custom.radio', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    toggleRadio($(this));
  });
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Without showing your CSS (and Javascript?) how do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: Sorry @JimGarrison, just etited my post. Thanks